# Elements in array lose value

Tags: ruby, concurrency, sinatra

I have a strange issue. That values from elements in my array disappear.

The Sinatra part looks like this:

```
config do
  $api = MyWrappr.new
end

get "/"
 erb :view, :locals => {:elements => $api.allElements }
end
```

So what allElements do is first check if there already is a array or not and then it check with the time if the array need to be refreshed.

```
def allElements
  @elements ||= getElements
  if Time.now-@time > 60
    @elements = getElements
    @time = Time.now
  end
  @elements
end
```

And @elements is an array with element this looks like this

```
class Element
  attr_accessor :property_1 :property_2
end
```

Now when I start my application which use thin as server, and I refresh the site fast enough :property_2 just disappear and become nil. Why happen this and how can I fix that?

Oh and if I describe my problem to abstract here is the full [project](https://github.com/l33tname/movie)

Comment: could you please include the error you are getting with enough context information?

Comment: I don't get a error, and what happen I describe here -> :property_2 just disappear and become nil

Comment: Your `allElements` method has at least one typo, you must mean `if Time.now-@time > 60` rather than `if Time.now-time > 60`. Also you call `getElements` then `getElement` but I guess you also meant `getElements` for the second one.

Comment: @user846250 The first thing isn't a typo, you can access class variable without '@' but I change it because it's confusing people, and with the second thing your right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just the short story I'm a bit stupid.

I have manipulate the object in my view like this:

```
<div class="title">
    <b><%= "#{element.property_1.slice!(0, 24)}" %><%= "..." if (element.property_1.length > 24) %></b>
</div>
```

And after that there is clear why property_1 is empty.